# Chrome extension : addEventListener Textbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just want to know if there's a Listener in chrome extension for a textbox onchange.

here's my sample code :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', function());
 document.getElementById('company_search').addEventListener('change', function()); 
});
```

the 'login' button is working but not the 'company_search' textbox.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Assuming you're running it after the element with `id="company_search"` exists, your second one (without "on") should work. Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks. I got it!.. I just need to not to focus the textbox after the typing to take effect the search. :)

Comment: by the way, how can I close this thread or set it to SOlved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('company_search').addEventListener('change', function());
```

This will work fine. Check in the developer console whether you are getting some error. I guess the element "company_search" doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: Or doesn't _yet_ exist in the DOM. Might need to wait until `DOMContentReady`.

Comment: May be the extension doesn't even load after the web-page is loaded. For example: CTRL+P may be the event after which the form of extension where "company_search" element appears. So, we can't be sure whether the "company_search" element even exist after the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Certainly, but it's a common case that scripts execute before static DOM is fully parsed.

Comment: @Xan: Yes, I've already loaded it via DOMContentReady and the 'company_search' does exist in the DOM.

-Akhil thanks for that, but I've already done it and nothing's happen.

kindly check my updated question thanks!.